# is it possible to create php socket server works as a service to .net application?

Tags: php, .net, sockets, server, client

I want to create a php socket server working as service to .net application.

I want to  create php socket server and using .net client connect to it and they communicate with each other and according to the message received on socket flow will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language of the applications is completely immaterial to the protocol used between them. 10 bytes of data on traveling over TCP looks exactly the same to both applications, until they decode those 10 bytes. After which the handling of that data depends on the each language's capabilities, it does not depends on the different languages compatibility.

The only noteworthy difference in capability between .NET and PHP, is that .NET can decode and represent a 64 Bit "Unsigned" Integer, and PHP can only represent up to 64 Bit "Signed" Integers.  This is not a serious limitation unless your protocol facilitates like-for-like remote object models.

Comment: my question is how this is possible? is there any way i can run php socket as service on webpage

Comment: You may be misunderstanding a little about sockets.  On a web page, your browser is the "application" and "apache" is the server, serving up content generated by PHP.  The protocol is HTTP. Apache <-- HTTP --> Browser.

Comment: So you are creating an server in PHP, without apache, and your .NET application will connect to it.  So yes, its possible, and people most likely do it all the time.  PHP <-- Your Protocol --> .NET Application.  Tutorials on socket servers are available on the web, a good place to start is ReactPHP.

Comment: actually we are making one liquid dispensing machine  so from web page we will order on socket to dispense 50 ml .net application will read from socket and order machine to dispense 50 ml something like this. Is this possible?

my role here is to make socket and give order and listen to socket because on success we need to get success flag from machine using socket

Comment: Is the .NET app running on the dispenser?

Comment: dispenser will be connected to computer with usb and .net will be running on that computer so using .net command will be given to dispenser to dispense liquid

Comment: Then the socket server should be running as a daemon on the .NET application.  A website (PHP) will on request open a client socket, connect to the dispenser server, submit data, await responses etc, then close the connection.  You don't need PHP sockets for this.  You should discuss this with your team, something like that should have been thought of already.  You could probably even run IIS on that computer and just accept HTTP requests which are then used to control the dispenser, no fancy solutions needed.

Comment: but there will be more then one user who will use this system so on every computer i need to run one .net socket server and create client for that account ?

means x number of user will be there with x number of accounts and x number of machine

Comment: any one here please help me!